# Web service API for DRMAA on SGE

Tags: sungridengine, drmaa

Does anyone know of any project to expose the [DRMAA API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRMAA) (job scheduling and maintenance API) from [SGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Grid_Engine) (Sun Grid Engine) as a web service API? A RESTful API would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there are any web service API for SGE. I found [drmaa-python](http://code.google.com/p/drmaa-python/) pretty easy implementing in python script that can be called from server side scripts like PHP.

Comment: Thanks. I've kinda given up on SGE. The documentation is just too much of a pain to navigate :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If you decide to go onto it someday, i could help if you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like this available at the moment, but:

The Open Grid Forum started a new standardization activity to define how DRMAAv2 can be exposed as RESTful API. The [specification draft](http://bit.ly/zIaQGe) is publicly available.

Since more and more people ask for such a remote interface, implementations might be available pretty soon. They are most likely to be announced by the [OGF OCCI working group](http://occi-wg.org/), so follow them if you are still interested.

Mapping such an implementation to the DRMAAv1 library in GridEngine should be relatively straightforward.